# Groupby and join multiple rows based on datetime in another column?

Tags: python, pandas

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([['a', 'a', 'b', 'b'], [1, 1, 2, 2], 
                            ['k', 'l', 'm', 'n'], ['2015-08-01', '2015-06-01', '2019-11-30', '2020-01-05']]).T, 
                  columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])

df['d'] = pd.to_datetime(df['d'])

df.groupby(['b']).agg({'a': ', '.join, 'c': ', '.join})

    a       c
b       
1   a, a    k, l
2   b, b    m, n
```

Desired output:

```
    a       c
b       
1   a, a    l, k
2   b, b    m, n
```

I want to join strings based on old date to new date.

In the desired output if you see column c, we have l, k in first row rather than k, l this is because if you see the datetime (i.e column d) provided K = 2015-08-01 where as L = 2015-06-01 here L has least datetime so it should come first when joining.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost there, just `sort_values(...)` before `groupby()`:

```py
df=df.sort_values("d", axis=0)

df2=df.groupby(['b']).agg({'a': ', '.join, 'c': ', '.join})
```

Output:

```py
      a     c
b
1  a, a  l, k
2  b, b  m, n
```

Comment: The bit with converting to date time is already there, I didn't want to repeat the whole code from the question;) I prefer to have ```axis``` explicit - but yeah, it's a matter of preference.

Comment: Fair enough, and I missed out on the pd.to_dateime :)